# Youtube api inside a function not working

Tags: javascript

Messing around and trying make a YouTube video load on specific page, only load on desktop and pass in an video ID. So I have to put it into function. But for reason beyond my understanding my attempts fail, been trying for 3 days :) My script works when you remove the function `inyectYT(ytid)` and `videoId: ytid` and replace it with the commented code below it.

Sure its something simple like always, please take a look, thanks.

```js
console.clear();

function inyectYT(ytid) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var done = false;
  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (
      !done &&
      (!this.readyState ||
        this.readyState === "loaded" ||
        this.readyState === "complete")
    ) {
      done = true;
      script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = ytPlayerInit(ytid);
    }
  };
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function ytPlayerInit(ytid) {
  console.log(ytid);

  var playerOptions = {
    // Autoplay + mute has to be activated (value = 1) if you want to autoplay it everywhere
    // Chrome/Safari/Mobile
    autoplay: 1,
    mute: 1,
    autohide: 1,
    modestbranding: 1,
    rel: 0,
    showinfo: 0,
    controls: 0,
    disablekb: 1,
    enablejsapi: 1,
    iv_load_policy: 3,
    loop: 1
  };

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var ytPlayer;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(ytid) {
    ytPlayer = new YT.Player("player", {
      width: "1280",
      height: "720",
      videoId: ytid,
      //videoId: "M7lc1UVf-VE",
      playerVars: playerOptions,
      events: {
        onReady: onPlayerReady
        // 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
}

//dom ready

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (
    document.readyState == "interactive" &&
    document.querySelector(".container").classList.contains("home")
  ) {
    inyectYT("M7lc1UVf-VE");
  }
};
```

```css
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container home">
<div id="player"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with this line:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(ytid) {
```

First, declaring a function inside of another function only makes it accessible within that outer function. The code you're loading from YouTube won't be able to find it. You could make it global by attaching it to the `window` object.

Second, when this function is called, it won't receive a `ytid` argument. What you want to do is use the `ytid` that `ytPlayerInit` received. You can simply remove the parameter from `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` (because JS functions are closures).

That gives us this line:

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
```

---

I also want to point out that

```
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = ytPlayerInit(ytid);
```

is equivalent to

```
ytPlayerInit(ytid);
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = undefined;
```

(`ytPlayerInit` doesn't return a value.) The code looks like you meant something like

```
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
  ytPlayerInit(ytid);
}
```

However, that's not what you want to do at that point in the code and what you have happens to work. (At least when I tested it. I don't know whether there is a case where you do need to set those handlers there).